# I'm sending _csrf token in form but still i am getting #400 unable to verify data submission in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

I'm sending _csrf token in form even in ajax post but still i am getting #400 unable to verify data submission in yii2. I don't want to use the following code to avoide this issue:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    eturn parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

This is not the permanent solution because applying this coded will breach the security here's my js Code.

```
 $(document.body).on('submit','form#send-resource-form',function(e) { 
    var form = $(this); 
    $.ajax({ url: form.attr('action'), 
      type: 'post', 
      data: form.serialize(), 
      dataType: 'json', 
      beforeSend: function(){ 
        // Handle the beforeSend event showLoader(); 
      }, 
    })
    .done(function( response ) { 
       removeLoader(); 
       if(response.status==1) { 
          mytargeted code. 
       } 
    }) 
 });
```

here's my console headers and response

Headers Image
[image: as you can see I m sending csrf token]

Response Image
[image: and what I get in response]

please any one know how to resolve this issue that would be a great help

Thanks

Comment: Show us your js code

Comment: I've a lot of js code file can you please be precise about the js code? soju

Comment: The code you are using to send ajax request of course...

Comment: $(document.body).on('submit','form#send-resource-form',function(e)
    {
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'), //form.attr('action'),
            type: 'post',
            data: form.serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
                // Handle the beforeSend event
                showLoader();
            },
        }).done(function( response )
        {
            removeLoader();
            if(response.status==1)
            { 
                mytargeted code.
            } 
        })
    });

Comment: Edit your question to add this code with the correct format. And take a look at your debug logs to see if the request is correctly send to yii.

Comment: it's sending _csrf token in the headers of ajax post. I've alos added the code into the question.

Comment: show the log of form.serialize() , are you getting the _csrf key ?

Comment: @AliAbdullah  can u see X-CSRF-Token key in your header. and if yes check if both the values i.e of X-CSRF-Token and _csrf are same or not

Comment: Yes both are same.. can't figure out why this is happening i can use $this->enableCsrfValidation = false; to make it working but this is not ht correct way to handle this.

Comment: @AliAbdullah yes definitely not the way .. what data you are sending ? by any chance you are using form to upload files ?

Comment: I am sending  "data: form.serialize(),"  that serialize the form and forward it to the controller...

Comment: @AliAbdullah yes but check the payload size which you are sending, with the upload limits in your php.ini . excedding the upload limit can also cause this

Comment: @KandarpPatel I've change post_max_size from 3MB to 100MB but still getting the same error :(